# Trouble getting input value

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm having trouble trying to log the value of a input.

So my script is showing below.

```
document.getElementById("news").innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">';

var x = document.getElementById("news").value;
console.log(x)
```

I expected it to log "Mickey" to the console. Instead it logs "undefined"

Can someone help me understand why and possibly help me with a solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: `news` is not an input-like field, so it doesn't have a `value`. Access its child instead

Comment: Well it changes the element into a input. It sets the value to "Mickey" but when it logs. It simply prints "undefined", but on the site I can see the "Mickey" value clear as day.

Comment: No, the `news` element stays as-is - it just has its children (if any) replaced with the input

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the value from wrong element. Try using the input Id and you'll get results.

```
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
```

You need to get the value from input id--^

```js
document.getElementById("news").innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">';

var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
console.log(x)
```

```html
<div id="news">
</div>
```